# Converting Rails 4 has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, associations, model-associations

How do you convert an older Rails has_many with :conditions to the new -> syntax?

Here is the has_many:

```
  has_many assets_name.to_sym, through: :associated_assets,
    conditions: { assets: { type: asset_subclass_name } },
    source: asset_subclass_name.underscore
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The procedure is to convert the condition block to a valid rails 4 conditional inside the -> {}.  The conditional needs to be the second argument to the has_many.

```
has_many assets_name.to_sym, -> { where(type: asset_subclass_name)},
  through: :associated_assets,
  source: asset_subclass_name.underscore
```